# how to change an imageView inside a navigationView using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigationview

I am trying to change the imageView inside of a navigation view (seperate layout file).
I have tried inflating the view to the layout in question, and then finding the I.D.
From there I used setImageResource on the I.D, but it doesnt change the image.

I am able to change the image using this code if the imageView is inside activity_main, however it doesnt seem able to change an imageView in a different layout file.

I dont understand how I cant change the Image even though I have the I.D of the imageView

My XML code for the navigationView (inside main activity):

`<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

```
`android:id="@+id/nav_view"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="match_parent"`
`android:background="@color/eerie_black"`
`app:itemTextColor="@color/white"`
`app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"`
`app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"`
`android:layout_gravity="start"`
`/>`
```

My XML code for the nav_header:

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
`android:orientation="vertical"`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="176dp"`
`android:gravity="center|bottom"`
`android:padding="36dp"`
`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`
`android:background="@color/celtic_blue">`

`<ImageView`
`android:id="@+id/nav_header_iv"`
`android:layout_width="75dp"`
`android:layout_height="75dp"`
`android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_supervised_user_circle_24"`
`/>`
`</LinearLayout>`
```

My Kotlin Code (inside main activity):

```
`val view = View.inflate(this,R.layout.nav_header,null)`
`val t = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.nav_header_iv)`

`val prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`
`val pictures = prefs.getStringSet("pic", setOf())!!.toMutableSet()`

`when(pictures.toString()){`
`"[0]" -> {t.setImageResource(R.drawable.samsung)}`
```